How many integers in {1,2 ..., 100} are divisible by 2, 3, 8 or 10 using inclusion exclusion principle
When I use brute force approach to answer this question it gives me exactly 67
a = 0
for i in range(1,101):
    if (i%2 == 0 or i%3 == 0 or i%8 == 0 or i%10 == 0):
        a+=1

        
print(a)

but when I try using inclusion-exclusion principle it gives me 73
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
    int n = 100;
    int cnt = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i<2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<2; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k<2; k++) {
                for (int f = 0; f<2; f++) {
                    int d = 1, nel = 0;
                    if (i) d*=2,nel++;
                    if (j) d*=3,nel++;
                    if (k) d*=8,nel++;
                    if (f) d*=10,nel++;

                    if (!nel) continue;

                    int sign = (nel%2)? 1:-1;
                    cnt+=sign*(n/d);

                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    cout << cnt << '\n';
    return 0;
}

Can someone please explain what is wrong here, I think it is because the GCD(2,8) != 1 and GCD (2,10) != 1

Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

All multiples of $8$ are always multiples of $2$. All multiples of $10$ are always multiples of $2$. By $S_{n}$ denote the set of integers from $1$ to $100$ which are all multiples of $n$. It suffices to find $|S_2\cup S_3| =50+33-16=67$.

@JoséCarlosSantos Then what is the use of title if you're not going to read it?

I never claimed that I (or anyone else) would not read it. The goal of the title should be to inform a potentially interested reader about the contents of the question. It should not be its first sentence.

The first thing I would try to debug the code would be to compare the lists.  What are the $6$ numbers one finds that the other doesn't?  What is special about them?  This is not a coding site.

You want to take the lcm of the elements, not the product.  For example, the intersection of multiples of 8 and multiples of 10 would be the multiples of 40, not just the multiples of 80.

Consider how the execution of your first fragment of code would proceed. Whenever i % 2 == 0 evaluates to true, evaluation of the rest of the or expression is allowed to terminate. So your i % 8 == 0 and i % 10 == 0 disjuncts have no practical effect whatsoever.
And that’s sort of the idea of inclusion-exclusion. We take an initial stab, but because we know that it was, say, an overcount, we adjust with a subtraction. But since that subtraction itself was likely excessive, we correct for that by another addition. But since that second correction was likely excessive, …, etc. We iterate in a fairly recursive manner, alternating between inclusions and exclusions, until we have converged on the answer.
With this problem, that approach would be to first account for the values of the form $2n$, $3n$, $8n$, and $10n$. Then correct for the double counting of any values of the form $6n$, $16n$, $20n$, $24n$, $30n$, and $80n$. Next, re-correct for the further double counting just performed, In other words, for the values of the form $48n$, $60n$, $160n$, and $240n$. And finally correct for the last double counting, which is the one involving any values of the form $480n$.
